# python vs CLI: how to print out and ask for the input simultaneously?

Tags: python, command-line-interface

Let's say I want to construct a timer for the command line, which could tick tock and -- at the same time -- ask and react to user's commands (e.g., stop, start, reset).

I know I can print at the same line with something like

```
for i in range(0,99):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    sys.stdout.write(str(i)+"\r")
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

But how about adding request for a user's input? Let's say I want the next line of program's output to correspond in code to something like `raw_input("Please, enter your command: ")`

I.e., for a user that could look that way:

```
0:53.1
Please, enter your command:
```

With these numbers, obviously, changing as the time flies by :).

Is it possible? How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Python curses](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html)

I have some code [here](https://github.com/dhui/diceware/blob/master/diceware.py) that uses curses.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use curses for this. But if you can't for some reason, you might have a look at [Pythons select package](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/select.html) (if you are working with Linux) or try to solve your problem with threading and queues (which would work under Windows, too).